# Excel Userform- Is there a way to have a label calculate a score based on the "Yes" or "Partially" responses of 7 from comboboxs?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have an Excel Userform which has 7 comboboxes with the options N/A, Yes, No and Partially. I would like to create a total score based on the responses in each of the comboboxes in a label on the form that would calculate as the boxes are updated or on a button click(really doesn't matter). 
Yes = 1
Partially = 0.5
To get the score I also need a count of the yes and Partially results as the score will be the sum of Yes and Partially/7.

I can't seem to get a label to update with any basic results however.

I have tried looking for code that's already out there but everything I find is referencing the actual excel worksheet/cells and not the immediate results in the userform or they are adding actual numbers and not converting text results to a number to be calculated.

This nested if statement is just my most recent attempt at trying to get even one of the comboboxes to populate into a label for me with no luck.

```
Private Sub Score_Change()

If CBCoverage.Value = "Yes" Then LBLCYes = 1
 Else: LBLCYes = 0
If CBCoverage.Value = "Partially" Then LBLCPartially = 0.5
 Else: LBLCPartiall = 0
End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

I don't expect you to write the whole thing for me but if you could just help me see what I am doing wrong here that would be amazing!
My comboboxs are named:
CBCoverage
CBInvestigation
CBFinancials
CBAutoPD
CBEvaluation
CBDocumentation
CBCommunication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attached this code to a button the form. It loops through each combobox on the form so if there are some you want to exclude the loop would need amending.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim c As Control, nYes As Long, nPartial As Long

For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "ComboBox" Then
        If c.Value = "Yes" Then nYes = nYes + 1
        If c.Value = "Partially" Then nPartial = nPartial + 1
    End If
Next c

MsgBox "There were " & nYes & " Yes, and " & nPartial & " Partial answers."

End Sub
```

Based on `nYes` and `nPartial` you could calculate an overall weighted score, e.g.

```
nYes + nPartial * 0.5
```

Comment: Hey SJR- This worked beautifully, Thank you! I took what you gave me and just modified it slightly so that it populates in a txtbox but what I am struggling to get working now is if I put this in: TXTScore = Format((nYes + nPartial * 0.5) /7, "Percent") it gives me the % however I realized that not ever case will have 7 responses.… so what do I put to make it divide by the sum of the nYes and nPartial answers so that its dynamic instead of fixed?